# In Dependency Injection, who is the client and injector and service?

Tags: dependency-injection

I was reading here, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection, and I am having difficulty figuring out who's who in the process.

If I have a plugin, am I the client?  Who's doing what with the various ways to do the injection?

EDIT:  Added service.

Comment: Hopefully, this article might make some of it clearer: http://www.infoq.com/articles/Succeeding-Dependency-Injection

Comment: plugin is the service, that used in the client code/class through DI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DI used for more abstraction...

```
//Service
Plugin mySuperPlugin = new MySuperPlugin();

//Injecting constructor style
Client client = new Client(mySuperPlugin);
```

or setter style:

```
Client client = new Client();
client->loadPlugin(mySuperPlugin);
```

instead of

```
public class Client {
    private Plugin plugin;

    Client() {
        this.plugin = new MySuperPlugin();
    }
}
```

We shouldn't hardcode any concrete classes in the implementations...

**Upd:**

DI required always, when we need to add dependency.

For example:

- We have some Class which do anything, send mails for example
- We want to log all this class actions
- We have clever class FileLogger for this

Let's code:

```
public class Mailer {
    private FileLogger logger;

    Mailer() {
        this.logger = new FileLogger();
    }
    public void send(String email, Srting text) {
       //send email
       this.logger.log(email, text);
    }
}
```

All right, yes?

But you write some new Logger and want to use it... How? 
You should change Mailer for this... 
It's always bad, because logger isn't the aim of Mailer class...

DI allow us to restrict interface only

```
Mailer(ILogger logger) { this.logger = logger; }
```

or if you want switch loggers after class instantiate

```
public setLogger(ILogger logger){ this.logger = logger;}
```

Now you can use all logger classes which implements ILogger interface...

It's very flexible...

Comment: Dumb question.  Client is the "other" guys program, right?  I thought DI didn't require me to do anything in the client's program with a plugin.  Are you showing me examples with and without plugins?

Comment: @johnny, I add example to answer... Which language you're write? I'm PHP developer, and can make some errors in code above... Look on it, as on pseudo-code...

Comment: Mailer is client, logger is service and guy which instantiate some logger and pass(inject) it to mailer is injector)

Comment: great answer.  Thanks.  Which one is the dependent?

Comment: Mailer dependent from some ILogger instance, sure. Logger doesn't knows anything about Mailer, but Mailer should correct execute this->logger ->log method... It dependent from a logger at this point.